# What makes you come back to Stack Overflow every day?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I know this is not a programming question.  Let's try to label it a programming community question so that it doesn't get closed.  I've been wondering what makes the programming community so prone to helping others in stackoverflow.  Is this something particular to programmers? Do you think lawyers and accountants would help other lawyers and programmers as we do?

What makes you come back to stackoverflow every day?  It would be great to have an answer per reason so that we can get the list of reasons.

In my case, I come to stackoverflow to ask questions that I can't solve quickly, and to test how good I am when answering questions.  So far I’ve failed miserably at trying to answer questions but it has helped me understand how little I know.

Comment: It took me longer to get my login in meta stack overflow than it took to transfer the question. :-(

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/addiction :D

Answer (score 5):

***Boredom***, the reason for everything I do (minus the mail) on the Interwebs.

Answer (score 2):

... pellet bar ...  occasional reward ...  BF Skinner ...

Answer (score 2):

I answer questions, and the little number next to my name increases, and I feel good inside. For a few minutes. Then I need to see it go up again. After a while watching it go up by 10s wasn't enough -- I needed 15s to get that same feeling. Soon I'm going to have to start sifting through the bounty posts to satisfying my craving

Answer (score 2):

Yehhhhssss, my precious. Reputations it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hooked up.

You know, the first one is free...